# Deleting an element from a rose tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I am trying to delete an element from a rose tree in Haskell by giving the name of the parent of the node and the name of the node:

I have written this but it does not compile

```
deleteNode x parent (Branch x' trees) 
    | parent == x' = Branch x' $ if (head trees) /= x then ((Branch x []):trees) else []
    | otherwise = Branch x' $ (deleteNode x parent) <$> trees
```

The error is:

```
tree.hs:25:75: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ Rose t
      Expected type: [Rose (Rose t)]
        Actual type: [Rose t]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `trees'
      In the expression: ((Branch x []) : trees)
      In the second argument of `($)', namely
        `if (head trees) /= x then ((Branch x []) : trees) else []'
    * Relevant bindings include
        trees :: [Rose t] (bound at tree.hs:24:32)
        x' :: t (bound at tree.hs:24:29)
        parent :: t (bound at tree.hs:24:14)
        x :: Rose t (bound at tree.hs:24:12)
        deleteNode :: Rose t -> t -> Rose t -> Rose t
          (bound at tree.hs:24:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I have the following definition of a Rose tree

```
data Rose a = Empty | Branch a [Rose a] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

How to make it work and return a new tree that does not contain the specified element?

Comment: What is `parent == x'` supposed to do? This means that the "value" of that `Branch` is a `Rose a`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me why you need the `parent` here. You can implement a view as:

```
deleteNode :: Eq a => a -> Rose a -> Rose a
deleteNode _ Empty = Empty
deleteNode x (Branch x' trees) 
    | x == x' = Empty
    | otherwise = Branch x' $ (deleteNode x) <$> trees
```

In case we thus found the item (`x == x'`), then we return `Empty`, otherwise we recurse on the leaves.

Note that this function will remove *all* branches that have `x` as "label", so if there are multiple directories `foo/`, it will remove all of them.

If `parent` is the name of the `parent` node, you can work with:

```
deleteNode :: Eq a => a -> a -> Rose a -> Rose a
deleteNode _ _ Empty = Empty
deleteNode parent x (Branch x' trees) 
  | parent == x' = Branch x' (map (go x) trees)
  | otherwise = Branch x' $ (deleteNode parent x) <$> trees
  where go _ Empty = Empty
        go x b@(Branch x' _)
          | x == x' = Empty
          | otherwise = b
```

This will remove all items which have as label of the parent `Branch` the value `parent`, and `x` as own value. There can however still be multiple items in the tree with `foo` as parent, and `bar` as label such that these will *all* be removed.

Comment: I wanted to specify parent cause as you said it will remove all branches that have the label 'x' and I wanna specify a subtree that it has this element 'x'

Comment: @Vanessa: but then the second parameter can be the subtree where you will remove all `x`s. You thus can call it with `parent` as second parameter, and `x` as the query.

Comment: something like that?

deleteEl _ Empty = Empty
deleteEl x parent (Branch x' trees) 
    | x' == parent = (deleteNode x trees)
    | otherwise = Branch x' $ (deleteEl x parent) <$> trees

Comment: But this is not compiling either..

Comment: It makes no sense to compare `x'` to a `parent`: the `parent` is a `Rose a`, whereas `x'` is an `a`, so the two can not be compared.

Comment: No, parent will be a name of the parent node.

Comment: @Vanessa don't you want the _path_ to the parent node? i.e. the list of all the labels leading to the parent node where you will remove `x` from?

Comment: Nope, just the parent's name. Sorry to bother you again but I get this error when I use the function :(

<interactive>:586:1: error:
    * No instance for (Show (Rose [Char] -> Rose [Char]))
        arising from a use of `print'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: I am calling deleteNode "dir1" "dir3", where dir1 is the parent of dir3

Comment: @Vanessa: that's because you did not call `deleteNode` properly: you forgot the tree where you want to delete the node(s) from. You need to call it with `deleteNode labelOfParent label someTree`, with `labelOfParent` and `label` the `String`s in this case, and `someTree` a `Rose String`.